# Postman API request in Python

Tags: python, api, postman, pfx

I am trying to web-scrape data from https://www.mcmaster.com. They have provided me with a .pfx file and a passphrase. When making a GET request on Postman using their .json file, I input my website login/password and upload the .pfx certificate with its passphrase and everything works fine. Now I am trying to do this same thing but in Python, but am a bit unsure.

Here is my current Python code, I am unsure where I would put the website email/password login and how to successfully do a GET request.

```
import requests_pkcs12
from requests_pkcs12 import get

r = get('https://api.mcmaster.com/v1/login', pkcs12_filename='Schallert.pfx', pkcs12_password='mcmasterAPI@1901')

response = requests_pkcs12.get(r)

print(response.text)
```

Here is how I have it setup in Postman (Website email/pw login)
[image]

.PFX Certificate page
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Postman has a built in feature where it will convert requests into code. You can do it like so:

1. On the far right click the Code Snippet Button (</>)
2. Once you are on that page, there is two available python options
3. Then all you need to do is copy the code into a Python file and add all your customizations (Should be already optimized)

> One thing I’ll warn you about though is the URL. Postman doesn’t add
> http:// or https:// to the URL, which means Python will throw a No
> Scheme Supplied error.

Available Packages for Auto Conversion:

1. Requests
2. http.client

Meaning you will have to use a different package instead of `requests_pkcs12`

Comment: I did exactly as you said and copied and pasted the code from the "Code Snippet Button", but it gives me an error in Python. Is it because I am missing the .pfx file? 

`import requests

url = "https://api.mcmaster.com/v1/login"

payload = "{\n    \"UserName\":\"purchasing@schallertenterprises.com\",\n    \"Password\":\"PASSWORD123\"\n}"
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer RVVZbEs284796820187waFZrVGFBZ3E0a3VwQXJESTlnOWI0P=',
  'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
`

Comment: With both requests and http.client I am getting a SSL certificate issue/error

Answer (score 1):

The package `requests_pkcs12` is a wrapper written above the `requests` package. So, all the parameters that accept `requests` will accept by the `requests_pkcs12`.

Here is the source code proof for that. https://github.com/m-click/requests_pkcs12/blob/master/requests_pkcs12.py#L156

Also, from your screenshots, I understood that you are using `POST` not `GET`.

```
import json
from requests_pkcs12 import post

url = "https://api.mcmaster.com/v1/login"
payload = {'Username': 'yourusername',
           'Password': 'yourpassword'}

resp = post(url, pkcs12_filename='Schallert.pfx', pkcs12_password='mcmasterAPI@1901', data=json.dumps(payload))
print(resp)
```

Footnote: I hope the password `mcmasterAPI@1901` it's a fake one. if not please don't share any credentials in the platform.

Comment: I now get a successful login code <200> but on Postman, it gives me a Bearer token which I re-input to then retrieve actual data. I don't see the bearer token upon successful login with Python like I do in Pycharm.

Postman: https://gyazo.com/f0f7baec22146d03615849b413f410bb

Python: https://gyazo.com/69f513da4d2af3d427afb2ee18335948

Could you please help?

Answer (score 0):

After a quick web search, it looks like you need to create a temporary certificate as a `.pem` file, which is then passed to the request.

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager
from pathlib import Path
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

import requests
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import Encoding, PrivateFormat, NoEncryption
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization.pkcs12 import load_key_and_certificates


@contextmanager
def pfx_to_pem(pfx_path, pfx_password):
    pfx = Path(pfx_path).read_bytes()
    private_key, main_cert, add_certs = load_key_and_certificates(pfx, pfx_password.encode('utf-8'), None)

    with NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.pem') as t_pem:
        with open(t_pem.name, 'wb') as pem_file:
            pem_file.write(private_key.private_bytes(Encoding.PEM, PrivateFormat.PKCS8, NoEncryption()))
            pem_file.write(main_cert.public_bytes(Encoding.PEM))
            for ca in add_certs:
                pem_file.write(ca.public_bytes(Encoding.PEM))
        yield t_pem.name

with pfx_to_pem('your pfx file path', 'your passphrase') as cert:
    requests.get(url, cert=cert, data=payload)
```

Comment: Do I just include this code with the python code from Postman?

Comment: Where do I use my website login as well?

Comment: @Kaevonz pass the auth details in the header

Comment: I am a bit confused can you show me?

Comment: @Kaevonz https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-requests-post-request-with-headers-and-body/